# How can I use Bayes' Theorem or analog to compute two dimensional conditional probabilities?

Tags: bayesian, conditional-probability

I have Y categories with X divisions and given two marginal probabilities and one conditional probability

Given two marginal likelihoods:

$\sum_{j=1}^{Y}P(C_j)=1$

$\sum_{i=1}^{X}P(D_{ij})=1$

And given one conditional likelihood:

$\sum_{i=1}^{X}P(D_{ij}|C_j)=1$

I would like to compute all the $P(C_j|D_{ij})$ values

By Bayes' Theorem a given $P(C_j|D_{ij})$ = $\frac{P(D_{ij}|C_j)P(C_j)}{P(D_i)}$ since the joint probabilities must be the same

However, this results in $\sum_{i=1}^{X}P(C_j|D_{ij})\neq1$ in the X dimension for a given $j$

If $\sum_{j=1}^{Y}P(C_j|D_{ij})=1$ can I interpret $P(C_j|D_{ij})$ as valid conditional probabilities?

Please let me know if this is the correct method to compute the desired conditional probabilities.

Comment: You should sum over j for a given $D_i$ to check to see if you correctly calculated the distribution of $C | D_i$.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by $$\sum_{i=1}^ P(D_i)=1 \text{for every} C_j$$ Are $D_i$ specific to each $C_j$, e.g. $D_{ij}$?

Comment: @gunes If $\sum_{j=1}^{Y}P(C_j|D_{ij})=1$ am I good to go? There is a different $D_i$ for every $j$ but $P(C_j)$ is independent of $i$

Comment: @jsk So is it alright if the vector of $P(C_j|D_{ij})$ values for given $j$ doesn't sum to unity in the X dimension? So that vector is not a distribution after all in X but is a distribution in Y?

Comment: The conditioning is incorrect in$$\sum_{j=1}^{Y}P(C_j|D_{ij})=1$$since the conditioning variable changes across terms.

Comment: @Xi'an source or proof? I don't follow your rationale.

Comment: It should be a fixed variable under which the conditioning operates.